# Matplotlib: add custom tick label and remove custom tick on y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to remove a tick and its label and instead add a new tick label in a different (but close) location without the tick itself. I am not sure how to do this. An example is given.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def main():
    fig = plt.figure()
    x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y = x
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    y_ticks = ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
    y_ticks[-1].label.set_visible(False)
    ax.set_yticks([3.7], minor=True)
    ax.set_yticklabels(["100"], minor=True)
    ax.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What is left for me here is to remove the ticks located at y=3.5, 3.7.

Also, as you can see I accessed y_ticks[-1] to set its label to be invisible. This was chosen arbitrarily and actually I would appreciate it if someone could explain why y_ticks[-1] chooses the tick located at y=3.5.

Thanks

[image]

**Edit:**

As was mentioned in the two answers I changed my code to:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    fig = plt.figure()
    x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y = x
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.set_yticks([3.7], minor=True)
    ax.set_yticklabels(["100"], minor=True)
    y_ticks = ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
    y_ticks[5].set_visible(False)
    y_ticks[6].label.set_visible(False)
    plt.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This yields the plot below and you can see that `y_ticks[5]` refers to the tick located at `y=3.5` and `y_ticks[6]` to the tick located at `y=4.0` - it skips the tick located at `y=3.7`. So how can I access it and remove ONLY the tick?
The two suggestions only explain how to remove either both tick and label or only the label (without the tick) and I am looking for removing the tick and keeping the label.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `y_ticks[-1].set_visible(False)` instead of `y_ticks[-1].label.set_visible(False)`. It makes both the label and tick marker invisible.

**edit:**

You can access the small tick at `3,7` using `ax.yaxis.get_minor_ticks()` like in the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = x
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_yticks([3.7], minor=True)
ax.set_yticklabels(["100"], minor=True)
ax.plot(x,y)

y_ticks = ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
y_ticks[5].set_visible(False)
y_minor_ticks = ax.yaxis.get_minor_ticks()
y_minor_ticks[0].label.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

If You want just the tick near `100` to disappear, and You want to keep the label, use:

```
ax.yaxis.get_minorticklines()[0].set_visible(False)
```

instead of :

```
y_minor_ticks = ax.yaxis.get_minor_ticks()
y_minor_ticks[0].label.set_visible(False)
```

All those functions allowing accessing different tick parts are described in `matplotlib.axis` [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html).

Comment: It seems that `y_ticks[-1].set_visible(False)` sets the tick at y=3.5 to be invisible but `y_ticks[-1].label.set_visible(False)` doesn't change anything.

Comment: @noamg `y_ticks[-1].label.set_visible(False)` is used in Your code to make the label near 3.5 tick invisible. If you use `y_ticks[-1].set_visible(False)`, it makes both the label and tick invisible, so You don't need it anymore.

Comment: You are correct , however I still can't get the tick at `y=3.7` to disappear. For some reason it is not in `y_ticks`.

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What happens is: You're getting the list of y_ticks **after** you've created an axes, but **before** you plot anything. So matplotlib sets up an axes with six ticks on both axes, from 0.0 to 1.0, and gives you the tick list.

Then, when you plot, more ticks are added and the ticks in your list are updated with the new labels. The last item in your y_ticks[] is now in the middle of the Y axis.

Solution: Plot first, **then** `y_ticks = ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()`.

Comment: I am not sure however that my y_ticks list is updated with the `y=3.7` tick. Therefore I can't access it to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found an answer. The added y tick at `y=3.7` was added to the minor axis rather than the major axis. Therefore I accessed it by `ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', length=0)`. This however will set ALL minor ticks according to `tick_params`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    fig = plt.figure()
    x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y = x
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.set_yticks([3.7], minor=True)
    ax.set_yticklabels(["100"], minor=True)
    y_ticks_major = ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
    y_ticks_major[5].set_visible(False)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', length=0)
    plt.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks for the help